# Can R autodetect the missing value in the formula and modify the output accordingly?

Tags: r, automation

Let's say I have a formula **area = length*width**.
I want R to modify the output such that if I give length and width as input, it gives the area as output; If I give area and length as input, it gives the width as output and so on.
I used the following:

```
dimensions <- function(len = NA, width = NA, area = NA){
   x <- ifelse(is.na(len) == TRUE, area/width, ifelse(is.na(width) == TRUE, area/len, len*width))
   return(x)
}

dimension(len=10, area= 100)

# output is 10 i.e. the width.
```

However, I don't want to define the relationships again and again even in the function. I want to write the relationship once, let us say, *len = area / width* and want a single function in R to keep modifying the output as per the input.

Is there any way to this?

**Edit 1:**
I read somewhere someone recommending python to do so with the following example of code written

```
from sympy import *
length, width, area = symbols('l w area') # defining symbolic variables
eq1 = Eq(length*width, area) # defining equation
print('length = ', solve(eq1, length)) # solving for variable length
```

However, if it's possible in python, how can it be done in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `missing` for this purpose:

```r
dimensions <- function(len, width, area )
{
  if(missing(len) & !missing(width) & !missing(area)) return(c(len = area / width))
  if(missing(width) & !missing(len) & !missing(area)) return(c(width = area / len))
  if(missing(area) & !missing(width) & !missing(len)) return(c(area = len / width))
  stop("Need 2 out 3 from len, width and area for valid output")
}

dimensions(len = 10, width = 2)
#> area 
#>    5

dimensions(area = 20, len = 10)
#> width 
#>     2

dimensions(width = 2, area = 20)
#> len 
#>  10

dimensions(width = 2)
#> Error in dimensions(width = 2): Need 2 out 3 from len, width and area for valid output

dimensions(width = 2, len = 10, area = 20)
#> Error in dimensions(width = 2, len = 10, area = 20): 
#> Need 2 out 3 from len, width and area for valid output
```

---

**EDIT**

An alternative (which may be more like the type of thing requested by the OP based on the comments would be to use `uniroot`, which will solve for the missing variable provided it is passed the equation in the form of a function that returns 0 when the equation is true (so, for example the equation `length * width = area` would be passed as `function(length, width, area) {length * width - area}`

```r
dimension <- function(...)
{
  areafunction <- function(len, width, area) { len * width - area }
  uniroot(areafunction, ..., interval = c(0, 1e6))$root
}
```

So this would give the results:

```r
dimension(len = 10, width = 10)
#> [1] 100

dimension(area = 20, width = 2)
#> [1] 10

dimension(area = 51.3, len = 4.76)
#> [1] 10.77731
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thanks for answering. I learned something new but this is different from what I was looking for. Your function is similar to what I created. However, if there is a bigger equation involving multiple variables, then such ifelse methods are not feasible. That's why I was looking for something which detects the equation, takes in the input, and gives the value of the missing variable. Something which reads equation rather than reading the ifelse statements we make. I am not sure if I am able to convey it now or not.

Comment: I have edited my question to give an example from python which I read somewhere, though I don't know python, can you elaborate more on how it can be implemented in R?

Comment: @kashj the python example still requires you to write one line of code for the variable you want to solve, the same as my R solution does.  You only need one line for each variable since only one variable can be missing at a time, so there is no combinatorial explosion to make it unfeasible. Can you give an example of an equation where this approach isn't feasible?

Comment: Allan. Consider a bit larger equation of the form  `x = (a*b/c) + (d*e/f)`. In this case, it is much better to define this relation once as in python example and just use solve() every time. However, writing a function like mine and yours will involve writing the different permutation of formula every time depending on the variable to be solved. In python code, we do not have to specify how the formula has to re-adjust to solve for the missing variable if you got what I meant. Can we do such thing in R: solving the equations.

Comment: @kashj your last comment was cut off, but I'm guessing you mean you don't want to have to rearrange the equation for each variable. In that case, you are probably looking gor something like `uniroot` - see my update

Comment: Allan. Thanks a lot. This serves my purpose. However, can you please explain it to me so that I know how to extend it to larger equations?

Comment: @kashj `uniroot` takes a function and tries it over and over with different values of its first parameter until it gets a result of zero. It does this intelligently so that it homes in on the right value quickly. Passing in the `...` means "use the parameters given in the outer function as fixed variables in the equation". Whichever parameter you _don't_ pass will be the one `uniroot` adjusts until it finds a value that makes the function return 0. The `interval` parameter just tells `uniroot` the range in which to find the answer.